# New theatre script

Tags: page-breaking

I'm slowly getting to the template of my script I'd like to get. However, the following code has two problems that I would like to solve:

1. The lines come out of the sheet on the right;
2. I would like the text in the command **\did** to stay attached and not split into two pages.
   Is this possible?
   Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nimbusmono}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\newlength{\postspeciskip}
\newlength{\standardindent}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\postspeciskip}{1.5\baselineskip}%
  \setlength{\standardindent}{0.2\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\standardindent}%
}

\newcommand\sce[2]{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus \baselineskip}
  {\newpage\LARGE\toleft{#1}#2\par}
  \nopagebreak
  \addvspace{6mm}%
}
\newcommand{\toleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\standardindent][l]{#1}}}

\newcommand\character[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.9\baselineskip plus 1pt}%
  \toleft{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
}

\newcommand\did[1]{{\raggedright\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}\par}}

\newcommand\g[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsl{#1}}}

\interlinepenalty = 1000

\setlength\parindent {0pt}

\interlinepenalty = 1000\parskip 0pt plus \baselineskip

\begin{document}

\def\HELLEN{\character{HELLEN}}
\def\MARTIN{\character{MARTIN}}
\def\RICK{\character{RICK}}

\sce{1.1}{The First Scene}

\did{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}

\HELLEN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna \g{(sub dialogue)} aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper \g{(sub dialogue)} suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\MARTIN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation\dots \g{(sub dialogue)} ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\RICK \g{(sub dialogue)} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\HELLEN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna \g{(sub dialogue)} aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper \g{(sub dialogue)} suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\MARTIN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation\dots \g{(sub dialogue)} ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\RICK \g{(sub dialogue)} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\RICK   Lorem\dots

\did{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`minipages` can be useful. Here is a slightly modified version of your MWE where I have used a `minipage` in the definition of `\did` and in the first speech by HELLEN.

```
% didprob.tex  SE 551856

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nimbusmono}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\newlength{\postspeciskip}
\newlength{\standardindent}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\postspeciskip}{1.5\baselineskip}%
  \setlength{\standardindent}{0.2\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\standardindent}%
}

\newcommand\sce[2]{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus \baselineskip}
  {\newpage\LARGE\toleft{#1}#2\par}
  \nopagebreak
  \addvspace{6mm}%
}
\newcommand{\toleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\standardindent][l]{#1}}}

\newcommand\character[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.9\baselineskip plus 1pt}%
  \toleft{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
}

\newcommand\did[1]{{\raggedright\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}\par}}
\renewcommand\did[1]{{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}\raggedright\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}\par\end{minipage}}}

\newcommand\g[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsl{#1}}}

\interlinepenalty = 1000

\setlength\parindent {0pt}

\interlinepenalty = 1000\parskip 0pt plus \baselineskip

\begin{document}

\def\HELLEN{\character{HELLEN}}
\def\MARTIN{\character{MARTIN}}
\def\RICK{\character{RICK}}

\sce{1.1}{The First Scene}

\did{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}

\HELLEN \begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna \g{(sub dialogue)} aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper \g{(sub dialogue)} suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \end{minipage}

\MARTIN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation\dots \g{(sub dialogue)} ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\RICK \g{(sub dialogue)} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\HELLEN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna \g{(sub dialogue)} aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper \g{(sub dialogue)} suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\MARTIN Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation\dots \g{(sub dialogue)} ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\RICK \g{(sub dialogue)} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\RICK   Lorem\dots

\did{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}

\end{document}
```

I'm unclear as to how you have set spacing for the text so you might need to alter the width of the `minipage`s